# How to use git with android libraries?

Tags: android, git, android-library

Like most android developers I use eclipse. When you set up a Android Library Project it is created in it's own directory.

Example:

/workspace/
/workspace/libproject1
/workspace/libproject2
/workspace/myapp
/workspace/mysecondapp

Now myapp will have a project.properties file that will have this:

```
android.library.reference.1=../libproject1
android.library.reference.2=../libproject2
```

And mysecondapp might have a project.properties file with this:

```
android.library.reference.1=../libproject2
```

How does this work with git? I check in libproject1 and libproject2 in there own repos. However if I use git submodules to connect the library project into myapp it wants to put them in a sub-directory. Then the project.properties files point to the wrong location. Is there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git has nothing to do with the setups unless you use them as sub-modules. I have been having the library projects in separate repos, and each time someone has to clone them, they should be cloning them into a common workspace folder. And it should work.

```
android.library.reference.1=../libproject2
```

This means, that Eclipse would try to find your library project in the parent folder. If it finds it there, everything else if fine. If not, you will need to manually tell eclipse where to find it if you clone the library in another location.

Personally, I would not prefer using sub-modules. I haven't tried though.

Comment: I went with sub-modules. I used a shell script to update them. git submodule foreach git checkout; git submodule foreach git pull